# Select two rows with one sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multiple-tables

Hi everyone I have this table structure

```
id | u_id2 | u_id2
1  |   8   |  10
2  |   10  |  1
3  |   9   |  8
4  |   1   |  8
```

With this sql query it try to get every friend relation with an 8 as user_id

```
SELECT 
      u.id              
FROM  up2_users u
RIGHT JOIN up2_friends f
ON u.id = f.u_id1
WHERE f.u_id1 = :user_id OR f.u_id2 = :user_id
```

The result is kind of okay but not totally correct. **:user_id = 8**

8, 9 , 1

You see in the table above that the 8 is the :user_id and it should return the 10 not the 8 from f.u_id2

But if I type

```
ON u.id = f.u_id1 AND u.id = f.u_id2
```

I get all results doubled and the 8s

Is there anyway to accomplishe what I need with in a single query?

The correct return should be 10, 9, 1

Comment: Dude... why don't you do it in two queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `join` for this query.  You do want to conditionally return the *other* user id, so use a `case`:

```
SELECT (case when f.u_id1 = :user_id then f.u_id2 else f.u_uid1 end) as id              
FROM  up2_friends f
WHERE f.u_id1 = :user_id OR f.u_id2 = :user_id;
```

If you don't want duplicates, then use `select distinct`.

Comment: Missing a comma after the case

Comment: @paqogomez - Its an alias name

Comment: @NoDisplayName with a dot?

Comment: @paqogomez . . . No, that was a copy and paste error.  But, it was missing `as id`.

Comment: And how would I do the call if I need the username from the users table?

Comment: You would have a different question, but you would really just use this as a subquery and join to the user table from this.

Answer (score 0):

@Konter Based on your recent comment on Gordon's suggestion, you might be looking for something like

```
SELECT 
  u.id
  , Friendship.friend2 friend
FROM  up2_users u
JOIN  (SELECT u_id1 friend1, u_id2 friend2 FROM Friend
      UNION ALL
      SELECT u_id2, u_id1 FROM Friend) Friendship
  ON u.id = Friendship.friend1
WHERE u.id = 8
ORDER BY friend1, friend2
;
```

Comment: What does friend1 or friend2 mean?

Comment: It's an alias as the sub-select does list all friendships twice - to allow access to all pairings regardless from the end, you start with. (Just drop the `WHERE u.id = 8` to see the effect.) Whether or not that makes sense depends on how you want to continue.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for the username

```
SELECT (case when f.u_id1 = :user_id then f.u_id2 else f.u_id1 end) as id,
        u.username              
FROM  up2_friends f
RIGHT JOIN up2_users u   
ON  u.id=f.u_id1
WHERE f.u_id1 = :user_id OR f.u_id2 = :user_id
ORDER BY u.username;
```